# How can a visa-exempt national visit Taiwan if they were born in mainland China?

Tags: taiwan

There are several countries whose nationals do not require visas to visit Taiwan for durations ranging from 14 to 90 days. [[Link](https://www.boca.gov.tw/cp-149-4486-7785a-2.html)]

There is also [another page](https://www.boca.gov.tw/cp-181-485-0b416-2.html) where it is hinted that people who were born in mainland China and acquired a non-Chinese nationality may need to prove that they have resided in their country of nationality for at least 4 years in order to be treated as non-Chinese for visa purposes. I imagine that the visa application process provides a means for such individuals to upload appropriate documentation.

In the case of a non-visa national who was born in mainland China, such as a Canadian passport holder, what is the process for such individuals to travel to Taiwan? Is there an expectation to carry documentation to show to the immigration officer at the port of entry that demonstrates at least 4 years of residence in Canada? Are there guidelines on what kind of documentation is considered sufficient, in order to avoid any issues at the port of entry?

**Please note, I am aware that most people currently cannot travel to Taiwan due to the COVID-19 pandemic. My question is about the situation that existed prior to COVID-19 and which will likely exist in the future after COVID-19 is under control.**

Comment: Last time I was checking, visa-exempt nationals are not, at least in practice, checked. But if your non-Chinese (PRC/ROC) nationality requires a visa, then you need to prove your residence when you apply for a visa, or an entry permit (if still considered Mainland person). But I cannot find a good source at the moment.

Comment: The only thing I can find at the moment is that the page for [visa on arrival](https://www.boca.gov.tw/cp-10-195-0a976-1.html) specifically mentions the restriction on former Mainland residents. Yet the page for [visa-free travels](https://www.boca.gov.tw/cp-10-4485-149c7-1.html) specifically mentions that Mainland-born passport holders of certain countries (e.g. Honduras) only are excluded from visa-free regime, but not more general restrictions for former Mainland residents.

Comment: English version of the page linked by zhantongz: https://www.boca.gov.tw/cp-149-271-2fdc9-2.html